# How to find & print throughput of API request received every 1 minute.have written this API request in spring boot (Number of request per sec, minute)

Tags: java, performance, spring-boot

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/discovery.conversations.recent")
public @ResponseBody ChannelsRecentList getChannelsList() throws InterruptedException {

    Instant start = Instant.now();
    ChannelsRecentList channels = new ChannelsRecentList();
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
        ChannelsRecent temp = new ChannelsRecent("ID"+randomAlphaNumeric.randomValueGenerator(),teamName,offset);
        channels.getChannels().add(temp);
    }
    Thread.sleep(1);
    Instant finish = Instant.now();
    long timeElapsed = Duration.between(start, finish).toMillis();
    logger.info("TimeTaken For ConversationList is "+timeElapsed+" ms");
    logger.info("Total ConversationRecent APICalls_Received_Count (30 per API Request): "+APICallReceived++);
    return channels;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you want to do load testing use a load test tool

Comment: Look for filters/AOP and collect those details withing filter/AOP if you really want to do this programmatically., as you are looking for Non Functional requirement

Comment: i want to handle it in code. and print the status of metrics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i made it to get throughput and system resources using

1. actuator/micrometer
2. prometheus
3. grafana.

as described in this [article](https://medium.com/@gopalkrushnapattanaik/monitoring-spring-boot-services-using-micrometer-prometheus-grafana-30106774372d)

Comment: This does not explain to future readers how and why this answers your own question –  _How to find & print throughput of API request received every 1 minute_. Also, any possible further explanation is potentially only given in the linked article (which may become unavailable at any given time). Please revise your answer so that is independent of an external article. For example, if your answer would show (and explain) how you applied what has been stated in the referenced article to your particular case then that would be most helpful to others.